# Angular Library without a workspace

Tags: angular, angular-components, angular-library

I'm trying to develop a new library that I intend to pull into three new Angular apps, as well as several components that extend one that comes from the library and are then used by those three apps. In my head the natural structure for this is a seperate repository for each app, the library and each component.

```
my-lib.git
app1.git
app2.git
component1.git
component2.git
```

However every article I have seen so far starts by creating a workspace and building the library in there. Since each component will be developed and distributed (via private Gitlab, not npm) on its own timeline, with the app devs choosing which versions of which components to include, it strikes me as putting them all into one repo isn't right.

What repository structure should I use for this and how do I develop an Angular library without
putting them all into a workspace?

Comment: Take a look at [**`nx`**](https://nx.dev/).